# derivative of a inverse function

Tags: differential, inverse-function

Let $f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 - 33x - 33$ for $x>0$ and $g$ be its inverse such that $kg'(2)=1$, then the value of $k$ is. Answer for the following is $72$.
I approach this question by $f\circ g=x$ but I got struck at part $f'\bigl(g(2)\bigr)=k$. Also I would like to know that does $g(x)$ will also be a cubic function as $f(x)$. If so any proof/counter- example for this.

Comment: Ever heard of the square root? That's basically why $g$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: I'm finding that $k\approx70.995$. Are you sure about the offered answer of 72?

Comment: yes! i am sure they let g(2)=x and solved the equation for fog(2)=f(x) from where x=-1,-7,5 and since x>0 which implies x=5 and answer comes out 72(exact)

Comment: use the chain rule : $f'(5)g'(2)=1$ and $f'(5)=72$

Comment: yeah but why use f'(5).